# Gutenberg select excerpt, use generated excerpt or use more block excerpt

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am trying to add the excerpt as a placeholder to a description field in the Gutenberg sidebar. The problem is that when there is no manual added excerpt the placeholder will be empty.

Is there a way to:

1. get the automatically generated excerpt?
2. get the paragraph before the "more block" (when it is used)?
3. if none of the above, how do I select the first block/paragraph without retrieving the complete content?

here is my withSelect code:

```
    withSelect( function( select, props ) {
        return {
            metaValue: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )[ props.metaKey ],
            metaExcerpt : select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'excerpt' ),  
            metaContent : select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'content' ),
        }
    } ) )( function( props ) {
        return el( TextareaControl, {
            label: props.title,
            value: props.metaValue,
            placeholder: props.metaExcerpt ? (props.metaExcerpt) : (props.metaContent), 
            help: props.metaExcerpt ? ('') : ('There was no excerpt found'),
            onChange: function( content ) { 
                props.setMetaValue ( content );
            },
        });
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get the automatically generated excerpt

The REST API always includes the auto-generated excerpt by default, so try with `getEntityRecord()` like so:

Note though, if the user edited the actual excerpt (i.e. the "Excerpt" panel in the Settings sidebar and not your `metaExcerpt` value), then the `currentExcerpt` would also use the excerpt the user has just edited.

```js
withSelect( function( select, props ) {
    const _post = select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPost();
    const post = select( 'core' ).getEntityRecord( 'postType', _post.type, _post.id );

    return {
        metaValue: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )[ props.metaKey ],
        metaExcerpt : select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'excerpt' ),
        metaContent : select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'content' ),
        currentExcerpt : post ? post.excerpt.rendered : '',
    };
} ... your code.
```

Then with the `TextareaControl`, use `placeholder: props.metaExcerpt || props.currentExcerpt`.

Comment: well thank you very much!  I have learned more from your answers here than from the developer handbook.

Comment: I would like to add that I have removed the HTML from the currentExcerpt with  .replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '') and removed the [read more] with .replace('[read more]', '')